# Win8 video capture in background

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can I record video from webcamera when my application (Windows 8 RP Metro style) isn't in foreground? What I need to use for this?

Comment: I do not believe that a `Windows 8 Style` and/or `New User Interface` application can be run in the background the same way a desktop application runs.  These applications were design to go into a restful state when they were not the focus, you can still for example check your email, and when the application has focus it updates the list of emails you recieved.  This is more inline with how iOS and Android work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Your application will stop receiving video as soon as e application is switched to the background.

There is no workaround or 'solution' to this.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, and your users probably wouldn't want it to be, either.  Why would you want to capture video without the user being aware that it is happening?

Comment: something like prey-project maybe? that's a very good reason to capture covertly